# How to add colored border in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to give bootstrap drop down a colored dropdown but did'nt know how to do that.
Please give any solution thanks..

```
.dropdown-menu
{
    border:1px solid #FC3;

}

<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: You want to add a background color to your `ul` dropdown or `li` items?

Comment: Your code should work just fine. You should put your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what else may be interfering with the `border` property. You should also be more precise: do you want the border on the entire dropdown, or on each menu item?

Comment: I want to give a border to the whole dropdown i.e. outer border of a dropdown. I think it will be ul.

Comment: you want border color in every li ?

Comment: no only a single outer border that will be ul.

Comment: Your code seems fine. I've tried a quick example in jsfiddle.The problem must be from something beyond what you've posted.

Comment: your code is fine it has already border color on ul

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing it in a different browser, or if using Internet explorer try changing browser version in F12 compatibility mode.  Bootstrap dropdowns can render differently across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert in your css

```
a.dropdown-toggle { outline: none}
```

Hope this helps you out ..